# Xcode autocomplete broken for .mm files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

Since there's no way to directly create .mm (Objective-C++) files in Xcode, I just create a CocoaTouch Class with Objective-C and rename the .m file to .mm file. However it seems the code autocomplete functionality is completely broken for .mm files, for example after I type "NS" I expect a list of "NSArray", "NSString", "NSLog", etc. etc. to show up, but now it only shows some code snippet shortcuts like "nsenum" and "nsoptions". If I rename the extension back to .m, the autocomplete works correctly again.

Now I wonder if there's some setting in Xcode to make the code autocomplete functionality work correctly for .mm files? So far I have not found any relevant setting, and keep renaming the extension back and forth between m and mm is really tedious after a while.

Comment: Are the search paths correctly configured?

Comment: There're no specific settings for Obj-C++ (search paths, but you can have custom C++ flags in build settings). Check them as a first thing as Matt pointed out. I remember having these sort of problems when I was using recursive search paths. Next thing to check is if your `.mm` file is marked as Objective-C++ type (select file, open file inspector, check Identity and Type). Then use Google and try other tips. I just tested it and it works as expected. Xcode is not reliable sometimes and one has to restart it, clean derived data, reopen project or even proceed with a computer restart.

Comment: It can also help to delete the project's derived data directory and to restart the Xcode app to make sure any stale caches are cleared.